# Not able to push files using clasp push command

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I am able to get the files using `clasp pull` command but not able to update the files using `clasp push` command. It says "No files to push".
When I run command `clasp status` then it shows all of my project files in "Ignore files". Previously it was working completely and the problem occurred yesterday when I changed my laptop.
I also tried making .claspignore file and it also did not work.

For reference, please see the screenshot.[image: Photo]

Please help.

Comment: There are no changed files.  Right? Change a file and push

Comment: @TheMaster, No, it was not about changing the file content and then perform clasp push. The clasp push works even if no changes are made in to the file.
Also, the issue is resolved now. I just uninstalled the clasp from my system and installed it again and now it is working file.

Answer (score 2):

I think for me I found the issue after using trying

```
clasp version "YOUR_VERSION_STRING".
```

I got a console message to enable API access. Once I enabled that I was able to make pushes. It's funny because I was able to clone and pull just fine.

So [this is the Settings URL](https://script.google.com/home/usersettings) and then make sure that "Google Apps Script API Access" is on.